# Html radio option text alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I'm having this issues with aligning the radio options. An example of what I'm trying to style is:

```
Question: How are you doing? 
A.I'm doing fine             B. OK                C. So so             D. not so good
```

A, B, C, D are each prefixed with a radio buttons with class = 'option'

To make sure the A's options (similarly, B's , C's, D's) are vertically aligned, I'm doing:

```
.option {
   width: 25%; 
   display: inline-block;
}
```

This works fine if the texts are not too long. If the texts are too long, I need to arrange them either as:

1) Having 2 options each line if possible

```
A. <long A text>                                       B. <B's text> 
C. <C's text>                                          D. <D's text>
```

2) Having 1 option each line if any of the texts is really too long for the setting 1) above.

```
A. <too long A text>
B. <B's text>
...
```

How can I achieve this effect? Any suggestions for CSS, Js are good for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on how the user is browsing the page? On larger resolutions, long text might mean 300 characters while on smaller resolution, it can e 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style and pad appropriately
html

```
<ul class="short">
  <li>a long text</li>
  <li>b text</li>
  <li>c long text</li>
  <li>d text</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul {
   width: 500px;
}
li {float:left; margin-right:20px;}
ul.long > li { width: 500px;}
ul.med > li {width: 220px; /* (500-40)/2 */}
ul.short > li {width: 105px; /* (500-80) /2 */}
```

js

```
find width of longest li and add appropriate class to ul
```

see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QqDgA/

Answer (score 0):

Use an unordered list as a container.

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

Style it so that the list items are 1/2 as wide as the list itself and float them left.

```
ul, li {margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none}
ul {width:500px:}
li {float:left;width:250px}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to check the length of characters in each item of the list, then have 2 different styles based on the number of characters. If any one of the items is over a certain number of characters you can then make the width 50%, instead of 25%.